# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.3.0-alpha01', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

When I try to import a Gradle project into my Kotlin Android project, I get this error message:

[image]

[image]

**Information**:

- JDK 17
- Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 Cancary 1

What could be the reason for this? I would like to use my Java project locally in my Android Kotlin app.